# VueJS Router cuts query params on live site, works on localhost

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, query-string

In my VueJS app I want to confirm a registration by traditional confirmation link.
This link looks like this

```
https://dev.xyz.com/auth/register-confirm?some=Data
```

Inside my register-confirm component I got the following method

```
    beforeCreate () {
      const query = this.$route.query // Is empty object on live page, works on localhost
      this.confirm(query)
  },
```

It is also very weird, that when I copy the original link to the browser and enter the site, it automatically cuts the query parameter, so the link looks like this

```
https://dev.xyz.com/auth/register-confirm
```

no matter what I type in as a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. We are hosting the site on AWS Amplify. It's caused by the rewrites / redirects.

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/97)